# How do I properly use completion handlers using swift & firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm new to swift. I'm trying to get the first name of a given ID in my code using a completion handler. My problem is that I want my handler to execute after getting the ID and then assign the returned value to a variable. how should I catch the returned value and use it right away?

This is my code in calling the handler together with ID and text.

```
let userId = data["MessageUser"]

self!.getName(id: userId!, completion: { fname in
      print(fname)
}) /* How should I catch fname so that I can use it. */

let text = data["MessageText"]
```

This is the code for the completion handler:

```
func getName(id: String, completion: @escaping (_ fname: String) -> Void) {
    let reference = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(id)

    reference.observe( .value) { (snap) in

        if let dictionaryWithData = snap.value as? [String:String],
            let fname = dictionaryWithData["Fname"]
        {
            completion(fname)
        } else {
            completion("error")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it by:

```
let userId = data["MessageUser"]

 self!.getName(id: userId!, completion: { fname in

                let text = data["MessageText"]

                if text != ""{
                    if let message = JSQMessage(senderId: userId, displayName: fname, text: text)
                    {
                        self?.messages.append(message)

                        self?.finishReceivingMessage()
                    }
                }
})
```